# java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: s

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to add data to SQLite database in android, But I am getting error, "java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: s". I tried to figure out the problem but I can't find it.

Button OnClickListener to add data to database.

```
 addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                    foodId,
                    foodItem.getName(),
                    quantity.getNumber(),
                    foodItem.getPrice(),
                    foodItem.getDiscount(),
                    foodItem.getImage()
            ));

            Toast.makeText(ItemDetailsActivity.this, "Item added to your basket.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Method to add

```
  public void addToCart(Order order){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetails(Productid,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount,Image) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
            order.getProductid(),
            order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice(),
            order.getDiscount());
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Comment: check database column datatype if integer or decimal then %i or %d

Comment: %d and %i cause error. And Database table is same, except i have ID extra in it, but it is auto generated.

Comment: Don't insert ProductId, only pass 5 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetails(Productid,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount,Image) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
>         order.getProductid(),
>         order.getProductName(),
>         order.getQuantity(),
>         order.getPrice(),
>         order.getDiscount());
> ```

You have six `%s` format placeholders but you're supplying only five values.

Comment: I forgot to add Image! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[MissingFormatArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/MissingFormatArgumentException.html)

> Unchecked exception thrown when there is a format specifier which does
>   not have a corresponding argument or if an argument index refers to an
>   argument that does not exist.

You didn't set a value for the 'Image' parameter